# Best lightweight. multithreaded windows web server for Ruby on Rails apps

Tags: windows, web-server, ruby-on-rails

I need to know what the best lightweight, multithreaded Windows web server is for running Ruby on Rails applications. I am currenlty using thin, but it is not multithreaded (by design).

So, what are people using on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

WAMP server will satisfy all of your prerequisites: http://www.wampserver.com/en/ It stands for **W**indows, **A**pache, **M**ySQL, **P**HP. It is multi-threaded and can run rails. It is very lightweight yet very customizable.

Here's also a guide for configuring Rails on WAMP: http://stmogilny.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/setting-up-ruby-on-rails-with-wamp/

Answer (score 0):

How hard of a requirement is Windows?  Could you run a Linux VM to run rails?

Performance wise they should at worst be comparable.  I'd be willing to bet that you would see a Linux VM run rails faster than the Windows host could.